# Elementary OS on Macbook 6.1 - big loss of battery energy

Tags: macbook, battery

I've installed Elementary OS on a Macbook late 2009 in place of the High Sierra that had issues (sudden and frequent reboots), Now it works well, I like the look, but the battery that previously had about 20 min autonomy, drastically diminuished in a few days, now it's 1%, in practice it must be continuosly powered. In terminal lshw shows unknown battery, I wonder if the battery is OK only Elementary is unable to recognize it or is it ruined definitely.
If the battery is ruined, I could buy another but surely don't want to ruin it too.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: macOS and Linux handle power management tasks very differently. Because Apple controls the full stack of their hardware and software, they can squeeze more life out of a battery charge. Linux *generally* operates with defaults and does not power down unused hardware as quickly or to the same state. For this reason, Linux-based systems will draw more power unless specifically tuned not to 

Comment: thank you, I understand (also from other posts) that elementary has some issues with battery, but what can I do? Is my battery ruined or it can be restored?

Comment: install tlp with `sudo apt install tlp && sudo tlp start` from terminal. If you want to finetune the settings follow this guide https://linrunner.de/tlp/introduction.html